# Enforcing jQuery select2 library in the dynamically inserted rows of a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I have an ASP.Net MVC Core web app that includes a details model **transactionDetails** that is tied to a master model **transaction** and they are connected by a **one to many relationship** so one transaction has many transactionDetails associated with it and I have managed to implement both of them in the same create view so that they can both inserted in one page and saved together to the database, and the way that the user inserts them is by inserting some data to the input fields of the transaction model attributes and inserts
data to input fields that are nested inside HTML table and the table body is inside a for loop to ittret through the values of the inserted list transactionDetails property that is associated with the transaction model and submit them and I have a javascript code to let the user insert new rows to the HTML table dynamically and submit the data inserted in those rows with the data in the static rows that were originally created by the HTML when the page first loaded, and I have managed to let the user to have a **searchable cell** (which is an input filed) to search from another table in the database named Account_Tbl by retrieving its data from a viewBag named ViewBag.accountList that ViewBag has a value of a SelectList that retrieve the names and Ids of the Account_Tbl and the ViewBag put the selected list inside a select element like this

```
<select  class="auotocomplate" asp-for="@Model.TransactionsDetailsTbls[i].account_id"
                                                                 asp-items="ViewBag.accountList"></select>
```

and the cell is inside the transactionDetails HTML table I did this using JQuery library **select2()** as shown here https://postimg.cc/w3pcvzrg

`so my problem is that when the user inserts new rows inside the table the searchable cell (which is an input field) become unsearchable and the JQuery library select2() does not work through the css of that  library is implmented in the inserted searchable cell.` Screenshot:https://postimg.cc/QFKZMcBB

Here is my models

```
 [Table("transaction")]
    public partial class transaction
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("transactions_id")]
        public int transactions_id { get; set; }

        [Column("date", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Date;


        [Column("amount", TypeName = "decimal(18, 5)")]
        public decimal? amount { get; set; }


        [InverseProperty(nameof(transactionDetails.Transaction))]
       public virtual List<transactionDetails> TransactionsDetailsTbls { get; set; } = new List<Transactions_Details_tbl>();    
    }


    //The transactionDetails Model


    [Table("transactionDetails")]
    public partial class transactionDetails
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("transactions_details_id")]
        public int transactions_details_id { get; set; }


        [Column("amount", TypeName = "decimal(18, 5)")]
        public decimal? amount { get; set; }




        [Column("details")]
        public string details { get; set; }




        [Column("account_id")]
        [StringLength(900)]
        public string account_id { get; set; }


        [Column("currency_id")]
        public int? currency_id { get; set; }


        [Column("refrence_id")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string refrence_id { get; set; }


        [Column("transaction_id")]
        public int? transaction_id { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey(nameof(transaction_id))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(transaction.TransactionsDetailsTbls))]
        public virtual transaction Transaction { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey(nameof(account_id))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Account_Tbl.TransactionsDetailsTbls))]
        public virtual Account_Tbl Account { get; set; }




    }


    //The Account_Tbl


    [Table("Account_Tbl")]
    public partial class Account_Tbl
    {


        [Key]
        [Column("accounts_id")]
        public string AccountsId { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
       

        [InverseProperty(nameof(transactionDetails.Account))]
        public virtual ICollection<transactionDetails> TransactionsDetailsTbls { get; set; }
      

    }
```

And here is my transaction controller

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            
     transaction transactionsobj = new Transactions_tbl();
     transactionsobj.TransactionsDetailsTbls.Add(new transactionDetails { transactions_details_id = 1 });
     transactionsobj.TransactionsDetailsTbls.Add(new transactionDetails { transactions_details_id = 2 });
          

     ViewBag.accountList =new SelectList(_context.Accounts_tbl, "AccountsId", "Name");
     return View(transactionsobj);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(transaction transactionsobj)
        {
           

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(transactionsobj);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(transactionsobj);
        }
```

And here is my Create View

```
@model transaction

<h6>Purchase Order - Create</h6>
<form id="CodeSbyAnizForm" asp-action="Create">

    <div class="row col-12">

        <div class="form-group col-2 ">
            data
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <input asp-for="date" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-2">
            amount
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <input asp-for="amount" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 ml-5">
            <table id="CodesTable" class="table-active">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            User account
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Currency
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Amount
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Refrence
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            details
                        </th>
            <th style="width:60px;">
            <button id='btnAddDetailRow' type="button" onclick="AddItem(this)">
               Add
            </button>
             </th>
                 </tr>
                </thead>

        <tbody id="CsDiv">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TransactionsDetailsTbls.Count; i++)
             {
             <tr>
                 <td>
                 <select class="auotocomplate" asp-for="@Model.TransactionsDetailsTbls[i].account_id" asp-items="ViewBag.accountList"></select>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                   <input asp-for="@Model.TransactionsDetailsTbls[i].currency_id" class="form-control" />
                 </td>

                 <td>
                   <input asp-for="@Model.TransactionsDetailsTbls[i].amount" class="form-control" />
                 </td>
                  <td>
                     <input asp-for="@Model.TransactionsDetailsTbls[i].Refrence" class="form-control" />
                  </td>
                   <td>
                  <input asp-for="@Model.TransactionsDetailsTbls[i].details" class="form-control" />
                   </td>

            </tr>

            }
                </tbody>

            </table>


        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
        </div>



    </div>

</form>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>$(document).ready(function () { })</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function () { $(".Select").select2() })</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.auotocomplate').each(function () {
                $(this).select2();
            });

        })

         function AddItem(btn) {

            var table;
            table = document.getElementById('CodesTable');
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length - 1].outerHTML;

            var lastrowIdx = rows.length - 2;

            var nextrowIdx = eval(lastrowIdx) + 1;

            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('_' + lastrowIdx + '_', '_' + nextrowIdx + '_');
            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('[' + lastrowIdx + ']', '[' + nextrowIdx + ']');
            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('-' + lastrowIdx, '-' + nextrowIdx);

            var newRow = table.insertRow();
            newRow.innerHTML = rowOuterHtml;

        }
        </script>
```

I have tried to unbind the javascript from the form after every insert to a new row using this var $form = $("#CodeSbyAnizForm"); $form.unbind();
and then reattach the select2() JQuery library, but I couldn't reattach the library
Best regards

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean when you create a new row of data, `select2()` becomes unavailable? But every time you successfully create a new one, you will be redirected to Index. Is there a problem with your second request? Please describe your expected results clearly.

Comment: @Chen yes when I create a new row of data, select2() becomes unavailable, My expected results are to use the select2() in every dynamically inserted row, please refer to this photo https://postimg.cc/QFKZMcBB to better understand what my expected results are, please note that I can't upload photos in StackOverflow because I am new.